# Capturing Borgia flags. What about Romulus Lairs?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

In AC: Brotherhood, I already got all the flags in all of Rome's districts.
My DNA menu shows me that I still need to grab some flags from secret locations. It seems these locations are the secret Romulus Lairs.

Do I have to grab the flags when exploring the lair for the first time, or is it possible to return to the lair afterwards to grab the missing flags?

Comment: @Mana: If you or LudoMC could edit this question to use the word "Lair" instead of "tomb", it would probably be better for future  search purposes, since the game calls these areas "Lairs of Romulus".

Comment: As I don't play the game in English, I didn't know what was the exact term to use. Change done.

Comment: Ah, I suppose that also explains why you referred to the DNA menu as "ADN", I was curious about that. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Yep, I missed it also :) ADN is the french for DNA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return later, but you don't do it by going back to the entrance on the map. Just open the menu, go to DNA, then to Secret Locations, and choose to re-play whichever ones you need.